# Create a ordered list (a-z) with the characters (letters and punctuation) in the sentence and how often each character appears

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, text

So I have a sentence that says

A guy walks into a bar and asks for 1.4 root beers. The bartender says "I'll have to charge you extra, that's a root beer float". The guy says "In that case, better make it a double.

I know that I probably have to use RegEx or something, as well as making sure that I spare based on spaces so that every word is done separately.

Also, I'm trying to do this on Python 3.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `collections.Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter
s = 'A guy walks into a bar and asks for 1.4 root beers. The bartender says "Ill have to charge you extra, thats a root beer float". The guy says "In that case, better make it a double.'
frequencies = Counter(list(s))
new_data = sorted(frequencies.items())
print(new_data)
```

Output:

```
[(' ', 36), ('"', 3), (',', 2), ('.', 4), ('1', 1), ('4', 1), ('A', 1), ('I', 2), ('T', 2), ('a', 18), ('b', 6), ('c', 2), ('d', 3), ('e', 16), ('f', 2), ('g', 3), ('h', 6), ('i', 2), ('k', 3), ('l', 5), ('m', 1), ('n', 4), ('o', 10), ('r', 11), ('s', 10), ('t', 14), ('u', 4), ('v', 1), ('w', 1), ('x', 1), ('y', 5)]
```

Comment: How do I get it to be ordered alphabetically?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest will be a [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter). You can then just sort its items:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> c = Counter(s)
>>> for char, num in sorted(c.items()):
...   print(repr(char), num)
' ' 25
'"' 2
"'" 2
',' 1
'.' 2
'1' 1
'4' 1
'A' 1
'I' 1
'T' 1
'a' 13
'b' 4
'c' 1  
# ...
```